# how set default type, collation and charset database in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

if i build schema with Doctrine 1.2 for Symfony 1.4 i must add options: type, collate and charset, for example:

```
AlSupplier:
  options:
    type: InnoDB
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    company_name:
      type: string(255)

AlCountry:
  options:
    type: InnoDB
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    country_name:
      type: string(70)

AlSupplierCategory:
  actAs:
    NestedSet:
      hasManyRoots: true
      rootColumnName: root_id
    Searchable:
      fields: [category_keywords]
  options:
    type: InnoDB
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    category_name:
      type: string(200)
    category_description:
      type: text
    category_keywords:
      type: text
```

how can i set default options (type, collate, charset)? I don't want every time this write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare them at the top of the schema.yml file and they will be applied to every table:

```
options:
  type: InnoDB
  collate: utf8_unicode_ci
  charset: utf8
```

Source: http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files#chapter_04_global_schema_information

Comment: thanks! and if a declare this on top, and i will for example for AlSupplier: disable collate that what i have to do?

Comment: @Beyed Black... not sure, probably safest to try it out first. My guess would be that whatever you declare at table-level overrides the global settings. That's how i'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Tom's solution.
[Another option](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5881) would be - if you want InnoDB to be used globally (e.g. also for plugins) - to define it in your `ProjectConfiguration.php`:

```
public function configureDoctrineConnection(Doctrine_Connection $connection)
{
  $connection->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_DEFAULT_TABLE_TYPE, 'InnoDB');
}
```